# Blazor WASM authorisation failure trying to access Register Page: DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have been creating a project in Blazor WASM and using Identity Server

all was working fine and Solution was being built up. however at some stage i must have altered a setting on Identity server as this is now preventing non-logged in users from REgistering or accessing logon pages.

trying to navigate to https://localhost:44351/authentication/register
i get the below console message in developer tools

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
```

as far as i can tell all is fairly standard

Login Partial

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using MDIS.SAW.Server.Models
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@{
    var returnUrl = "/";
    if (Context.Request.Query.TryGetValue("returnUrl", out var existingUrl)) {
        returnUrl = existingUrl;
    }
}

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a  class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="/" method="post">
            <button  type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl">Login</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Login Display

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <a href="authentication/profile">Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</a>
        <button class="nav-link btn btn-link" @onclick="BeginSignOut">Log out</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="authentication/register">Register</a>
        <a href="authentication/login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

St artup.cs

```
using MDIS.SAW.Server.Data;
using MDIS.SAW.Server.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace MDIS.SAW.Server
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<SawDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SawDbContext>( );

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, SawDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what else i need to share

Comment: Did you ever solve this. Exactly what I am looking at except I'm using Blazor.

Comment: Same here. After some edits it works sometimes. But without code changes it stops working after a few restarts.

Comment: @GPGVM same here

Answer (score 4):

I do not know how it work exactly but you should pass a string parameter `"auth"` when create Claimprinciple as shown below:

```
public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim( ClaimTypes.Name, "newbie"),
            new Claim( ClaimTypes.Role, "guest")
        }, "auth"));

        return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal));
    }
```

The string could be anything.

Comment: I was experiencing the same problem with authentication in MAUI Blazor and by adding the `"auth"` part when instantiating the `ClaimsPrincipal`, fixed the issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when my client_secret expired.  I issued a new secret and it worked.  Remember if you are using secrets.json for running locally you need to right click on your blazor server project and go to "Manage User Secrets" and update it there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was a discrepancy between the scopes defined in the appSettings.json:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
    "ClientId": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
    "ValidateAuthority": true
  },
  "GraphScopes": "User.Read;MailboxSettings.Read;Calendars.ReadWrite"
}
```

and the requests made of the `ClaimsPrincipal` (for me `User.Read` was missing).

A really good MS example (where I got the above) is:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sample-blazor-clientside

At time of writing this tutorial is using:
Microsoft.Graph 5.12 and
Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal 7.0.5

Answer (score 0):

For anyone here looking for a solution, encountering this issue with authentication in .Net MAUI Blazor the following helped me from the answer above by @hassane: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75357828/432074

```
var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim( ClaimTypes.Name, "userName"),
    new Claim( ClaimTypes.Role, "userRole")
}, "auth"));
```

The `"auth"` string needs to be added.